# Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run elastic search on docker 
I build a container for rails app connected with mysql container
I want to connect this rails  container with the elastic container
but I get this error

**Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)**

when I run docker-compose up 
these urls work fine
http://localhost:3000/

http://localhost:9200/

but I got that error with this url 
http://localhost:3000/messages

**Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)**

I want to get a response from this url 
http://localhost:3000/messages

how can I open port **9200** ??????????????

this my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: chat_system
      MYSQL_USER: appuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

elastic:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.0
  environment:
    TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP: "true"
    network.host: "0.0.0.0"
    http.port: "9200"
    transport.host: localhost
    transport.tcp.port: "9300"
    xpack.ml.enabled: "false"
# volumes:
#   - ./.data/elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  ulimits:
    nofile:
      soft: "65536"
      hard: "65536"

 app:
   build: .
   command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
   volumes:
     - ".:/chat_system"
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
   depends_on:
    - db
    - elastic
   links:
    - db
    - elastic
   environment:
     DB_USER: root
     DB_NAME: chat_system
     DB_PASSWORD: password
     DB_HOST: db
     ELASTIC_HOST: "localhost"
     ELASTIC_PORT: "9200"
```

I run this command to get elastic logs

```
     sudo docker-compose logs elastic
```

and I get this

```
Attaching to docker_chat_elastic_1
elastic_1  | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:29,261][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:29,722][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [WwjX-hI] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (overlay)]], net usable_space [735.2gb], net total_space [895.5gb], types [overlay]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:29,723][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [WwjX-hI] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:29,729][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] node name derived from node ID [WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA]; set [node.name] to override
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:29,730][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] version[6.4.0], pid[1], build[default/tar/595516e/2018-08-17T23:18:47.308994Z], OS[Linux/4.4.0-142-generic/amd64], JVM["Oracle Corporation"/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/10.0.2/10.0.2+13]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:29,731][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.arEsgr84, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,488][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [analysis-common]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [ingest-common]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [lang-expression]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [lang-mustache]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [lang-painless]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [mapper-extras]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [parent-join]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,489][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [percolator]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [rank-eval]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [reindex]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [repository-url]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [transport-netty4]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [tribe]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-core]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,490][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,491][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,491][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-security]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,491][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,491][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,491][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,492][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:31,492][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:33,514][WARN ][o.e.d.s.ScriptModule     ] Script: returning default values for missing document values is deprecated. Set system property '-Des.scripting.exception_for_missing_value=true' to make behaviour compatible with future major versions.
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:35,286][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [WwjX-hI] parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:36,476][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [WwjX-hI] using discovery type [zen]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:37,104][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] initialized
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:37,105][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] starting ...
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:37,256][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [WwjX-hI] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:40,338][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [WwjX-hI] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ], reason: new_master {WwjX-hI}{WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA}{iaR_00fyTMuqfMiCpiq1UQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{xpack.installed=true}
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:40,343][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [WwjX-hI] new_master {WwjX-hI}{WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA}{iaR_00fyTMuqfMiCpiq1UQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{xpack.installed=true}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {WwjX-hI}{WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA}{iaR_00fyTMuqfMiCpiq1UQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{xpack.installed=true} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ]]])
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:40,359][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [WwjX-hI] publish_address {172.18.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:40,359][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] started
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:40,672][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [WwjX-hI] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:40,751][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [WwjX-hI] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:42,283][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.watch-history-9] for index patterns [.watcher-history-9*]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:42,437][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.watches] for index patterns [.watches*]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:42,665][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.triggered_watches] for index patterns [.triggered_watches*]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:42,859][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.monitoring-logstash] for index patterns [.monitoring-logstash-6-*]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:43,045][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.monitoring-es] for index patterns [.monitoring-es-6-*]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:43,305][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.monitoring-alerts] for index patterns [.monitoring-alerts-6]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:44,163][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.monitoring-beats] for index patterns [.monitoring-beats-6-*]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:44,422][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [WwjX-hI] adding template [.monitoring-kibana] for index patterns [.monitoring-kibana-6-*]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T17:58:45,050][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [WwjX-hI] license [9f6ac6c0-620a-4b71-b3e7-da5bb37b8337] mode [basic] - valid
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:15,514][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] stopping ...
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:15,525][INFO ][o.e.x.w.WatcherService   ] [WwjX-hI] stopping watch service, reason [shutdown initiated]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:15,764][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] stopped
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:15,764][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] closing ...
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:15,770][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] closed
elastic_1  | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:28,430][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:28,776][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [WwjX-hI] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (overlay)]], net usable_space [735.1gb], net total_space [895.5gb], types [overlay]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:28,777][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [WwjX-hI] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:28,782][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] node name derived from node ID [WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA]; set [node.name] to override
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:28,783][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] version[6.4.0], pid[1], build[default/tar/595516e/2018-08-17T23:18:47.308994Z], OS[Linux/4.4.0-142-generic/amd64], JVM["Oracle Corporation"/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/10.0.2/10.0.2+13]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:28,783][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.wSQUCcFj, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,057][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,057][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [analysis-common]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [ingest-common]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [lang-expression]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [lang-mustache]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [lang-painless]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [mapper-extras]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [parent-join]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [percolator]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [rank-eval]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [reindex]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,058][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [repository-url]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [transport-netty4]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [tribe]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-core]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-security]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,060][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,060][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,060][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,060][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:30,060][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WwjX-hI] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:31,792][WARN ][o.e.d.s.ScriptModule     ] Script: returning default values for missing document values is deprecated. Set system property '-Des.scripting.exception_for_missing_value=true' to make behaviour compatible with future major versions.
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:33,335][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [WwjX-hI] parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:34,159][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [WwjX-hI] using discovery type [zen]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:34,790][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] initialized
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:34,790][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] starting ...
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:34,927][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [WwjX-hI] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:38,001][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [WwjX-hI] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ], reason: new_master {WwjX-hI}{WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA}{CzEAmK5jRsOh6lrRagMi_Q}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{xpack.installed=true}
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:38,005][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [WwjX-hI] new_master {WwjX-hI}{WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA}{CzEAmK5jRsOh6lrRagMi_Q}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{xpack.installed=true}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {WwjX-hI}{WwjX-hIPSZ-7L9XS1bYQFA}{CzEAmK5jRsOh6lrRagMi_Q}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{xpack.installed=true} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ]]])
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:38,023][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [WwjX-hI] publish_address {172.18.0.3:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:38,023][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WwjX-hI] started
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:38,721][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [WwjX-hI] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:38,762][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [WwjX-hI] license [9f6ac6c0-620a-4b71-b3e7-da5bb37b8337] mode [basic] - valid
elastic_1  | [2019-09-24T18:00:38,772][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [WwjX-hI] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Answer (score 10):

docker-compose exposes the service "elastic". This service is resolvable within your docker network so your rails app should connect like this:

```
ELASTIC_HOST: "elastic"
```

localhost in a container in bridge-mode is local to the container.

Comment: In other words, do not write `ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200` but instead `ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elastic:9200`.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @bjarte-brandt answer, you can create an initializer to setup the ELASTIC_HOST:

app/config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb:

```
config = {
    host: "http://localhost:9200/"
}

if File.exists?("config/elasticsearch.yml")
  config.merge!(YAML.load_file("config/elasticsearch.yml")[Rails.env].deep_symbolize_keys)
end

Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
```

app/config/elasticsearch.yml:

```
development: &default
  host: 'elastic'
test:
  <<: *default
production:
  <<: *default
```

Source: https://medium.com/@divyanshu.verma1993/configuring-elasticsearch-on-rails-8bcbe973e9e7

Answer (score 2):

this part of docker compose open the related port.

```
ports:
  - "9200:9200"
  - "9300:9300"
```

Does elastic start?
pls share:

```
docker-compose logs elastic
```

on your docker-compose you set elastic host to localhost of the container so it can not be published by ports:

```
transport.host: localhost
```

either config it to:

```
transport.host: "0.0.0.0"
# or even remove it
```

or sharing your network with docker container by adding this to your service :

```
network_mode: "host"
```